# What physiological pathways lie behind inhalants hallucinogenic effect?

Tags: neurophysiology, pharmacology, toxicology, psychoneuropharmacology

I searched through the web and surprisingly I found pretty much nothing on the physiology of hallucinogenic effects of inhalants. Any idea how people get high with inhalants (household and industrial chemicals) and what physiological pathway lies behind this mechanism?

Comment: Interesting question, although I'm not an expert on inhalants. But part of the many reasons of its psychoactivity may be of the less oxygen-saturated blood going to your brain (i.e. your body not having enough oxygen due to inhaling some gas).